# println in "call" method of "vars/foo.groovy" works, but not in method in class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm iterating through building a Jenkins pipeline shared library, so my Jenkinsfile is a little cleaner.

I'm using the following page for guidance: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ .

I first defined several methods in individual files, like "`vars/methodName.groovy`", with a "`call()`" method in the code.  This works ok, and I particularly note that "`println`" calls in these methods are seen in the Jenkins console output.

I then decided I wanted to save some state between method calls, so I added a new file in "`vars`" named "`uslutils.groovy`" that begins like this (minus some required imports):

```
class uslutils implements Serializable {
```

I defined some "`with<property>`" methods that set a property and return this.

I then wrote a "`public String toString()`" method in "`uslutils`" that looks something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    println "Inside uslutils.toString()."
    return "[currentBuild[${currentBuild}] mechIdCredentials[${mechIdCredentials}] " +
           "baseStashURL[${baseStashURL}] jobName[${jobName}] codeBranch[${codeBranch}] " +
           "buildURL[${buildURL}] pullRequestURL[${pullRequestURL}] qBotUserID[${qBotUserID}] " +
           "qBotPassword[${qBotPassword}]]"
}
```

Then, inside my Jenkinsfile, after setting the uslutils properties, I added a line like this:

```
println "uslutils[${uslutils}]"
```

Then, I ran my job, and the curious thing that happened is that I didn't see the "uslutils" line, or the `Inside uslutils.toString()`. line.  However, I did modify the one functional method I've added so far to "uslutils" (besides the "with" methods), which returns a string value, and I just added an "x" to the value.  My Jenkinsfile was printing the result from that, and it did show the additional "x".

Note that no errors occurred here, it just seemed to omit the `println` output from within the shared library class, and even stranger, omitted the output from the `println` call in the Jenkinsfile that was implicitly calling the `uslutils.toString()` method.  Note that the `println` calls in the original `call()` methods WERE seen in the console output.

Any ideas what might be happening here?

**Update**:

I now have the following lines in my Jenkinsfile (among others):

```
println "uslutils.qBotPassword[${uslutils.qBotPassword}]"
println "uslutils[${uslutils}]"
println "uslutils.toString()[${uslutils.toString()}]"
```

And to repeat, here is the "uslutils.toString()" method:

```
public String toString() {
    println "Inside uslutils.toString()."
    return "[currentBuild[${currentBuild}] mechIdCredentials[${mechIdCredentials}] " +
           "baseStashURL[${baseStashURL}] jobName[${jobName}] codeBranch[${codeBranch}] " +
           "codeURL[${codeURL}] buildURL[${buildURL}] pullRequestURL[${pullRequestURL}] qBotUserID[${qBotUserID}] " +
           "qBotPassword[${qBotPassword}]]"
}
```

Here are corresponding lines of output from the build:

```
[Pipeline] echo
uslutils.qBotPassword[...]
[Pipeline] echo
uslutils.toString()[[currentBuild[org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@41fb2c94] mechIdCredentials[121447d5-0fe4-470d-b785-6ce88225ef01] baseStashURL[https://...] jobName[unified-service-layer-build-pipeline] codeBranch[master] codeURL[ssh://git@...] buildURL[http://...] pullRequestURL[] qBotUserID[...] qBotPassword[...]]
```

As you can see, the line attempting to `print "uslutils[${uslutils}]"` was simply ignored.  The line attempting to `print "uslutils.toString()[${uslutils.toString()}]"` did render, but also note that the `Inside uslutils.toString()`. did not render.

I'm still looking for an explanation for this behavior, but perhaps this summarizes it more succinctly.

Answer (score 28):

I did some digging and found this issue, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41953, basically in normal pipeline script `println` is aliased to `echo` step. But when you're in a class, e.g. outside of the pipeline CPS, then the echo step isn't available and the `println` is ignored (since, as I understand it, there is no logger available).

What you can do is to propagate the script environment into your class methods using a variable and call `echo` through the variable ([found solution in this thread](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Logging-from-Custom-class-loaded-using-workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin-td4819953.html)). Like this:

```
class A {
    Script script;
    public void a() {
        script.echo("Hello")
    }
}
def a = new A(script:this)
echo "Calling A.a()"
a.a()
```

outputs:

```
Started by user jon
[Pipeline] echo
Calling A.a()
[Pipeline] echo
Hello
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Which is what we want. For comparison, here is without propagation:

```
class A {
    public void a() {
        println "Hello"
    }
}
def a = new A()
echo "Calling A.a()"
a.a()
```

Gives:

```
Started by user jon
[Pipeline] echo
Calling A.a()
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: have you ever tried to run this solution in a master/slave environment? it seems to fail when trying to serialize the script property

Comment: Yea you probably need to annotate the method A.a() with @NonNCP, class needs to implement Serializable interface which prevents and then pass Script as argument to the method...

Comment: I do not know much about the limits put on the pipeline by running in the context of a slave node, but a README of `workflow-cps-plugin` says, `You may not call regular (CPS-transformed) methods, or Pipeline steps, from a @NonCPS method, so they are best used for performing some calculations before passing a summary back to the main script.` https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/#technical-design

Comment: @eelghEEz Yes, so if you annotate a method with `@NonCPS` then you can not call any of the steps from the global scope, nor can you use the trick above, you will get an error when you try to reference things in the script variable above. This is regardless of what master/slave environment you are in. Do however note that print ant println is built in functions in groovy and thus is excluded from this, but as shown above, the message isn't always printed in the console output.