# jenkins pipeline function errors with no error

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a jenkins pipeline script to make product tests on our machines

the father of all tests looks like this

```
node('nightly-master') {

stage 'run'
println PRODUCTS
oliTest('win7.nightly.test', 'checkAndWaitForInstalledProduct.py', 'esxi', 'opsi-local-image-prepare', 'opsi-local-image-win7', PRODUCTS)
)
}
```

PRODUCTS is a textbox variable, enetered at the build start

the function oliTest() is this:

```
def call(SERVERID, CHECKSCRIPT, VIRTUALIZATION, OLIPREPARE, OLINETBOOT, PRODUCTS){

    try {
    timeout(time: 5, unit: 'HOURS') {
    println SERVERID
    println CHECKSCRIPT
    println VIRTUALIZATION
    println OLIPREPARE
    println OLINETBOOT
    println PRODUCTS
    //oliPrepare(SERVERID, CHECKSCRIPT, VIRTUALIZATION, OLIPREPARE, OLINETBOOT)
    oliProd(SERVERID, CHECKSCRIPT, VIRTUALIZATION, PRODUCTS)
    oliBackup(SERVERID, CHECKSCRIPT, VIRTUALIZATION)
    oliRestore(SERVERID, CHECKSCRIPT, VIRTUALIZATION)
    }
        } catch(error) {
    sh "fab -f /home/adminuser/scripts/${VIRTUALIZATIO}Nfab.py powerOffVm:vmName=${SERVERID}"
    sh 'return 1'
    }
}
```

the println values are printed correctly into the jenkins log
as soon as the function oliProd() is called the test fails without any error message at the forr loop in the following block

```
def call(SERVERID, CHECKSCRIPT, VIRTUALIZATION, PRODUCTS){

    stage 'install Products'
    println SERVERID
    println CHECKSCRIPT
    println VIRTUALIZATION
    println PRODUCTS
    sh " echo ${PRODUCTS}"
    sh "echo ${SERVERID}"
    sh "for i in ${PRODUCTS}; do opsi-admin -d method setProductActionRequestWithDependencies $i ${SERVERID} setup;done"
}
```

writing it multi line with '''COMMAND''' exists with an error, because ${SERVERID} is not expanded and left empty

Any suggestions how to make things work??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could use have triple double-quotes instead of triple single-quotes.  That would have fixed that simple problem.

However, you really should be doing your iteration in the script code itself, instead of trying to do iteration in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Jon S suggested to resolve script methods such as "echo" against a reference to the "pipeline object as in `oliTest(this, ...)` where `oliTest` declares a Script parameter and passes it along to other methods/instances to be used to resolve `echo` as `scriptObj.echo`.

[println in "call" method of "vars/foo.groovy" works, but not in method in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149652/println-in-call-method-of-vars-foo-groovy-works-but-not-in-method-in-class)