# Accessing Groovy class variables via Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a pipeline for my project using Jenkins Declarative Pipleline. As a part of it i had to write some Groovy code in some file and i was successful in loading it. Below is the a code snippet from JenkinsFile

```
stage('Pre-Build'){
        steps{
            script{
                 pipeline = load 'dependencyChecker.groovy'
                 dependents = pipeline.gatherAllDependencies("${base_workspace}/${branch}/${project}/settings.gradle")
                 for (item in dependents){
                    sh "cp --parents ${item} ."
                }
            }
        }
```

}

The following is the groovy file(dependencyChecker.groovy)

```
class Test1{

    static def outStream;
        static setOut(PrintStream out){
        outStream = out;
        out.println(outStream);

    }


    static List gatherAllDependencies(String settingsPath){
        List projectDependencies = [];
        computeAllDependencies(settingsPath,projectDependencies);
        return projectDependencies;
    }

    static List computeAllDependencies(String settingsPath,List projectDependencies){
        new File(settingsPath).splitEachLine('='){line ->
            if(line[1]!=null){
                outStream.println("Entire Project Name is ${line[1]}");
                def name = line[1].split('\'');
                if(name.length==3){
                    def dir = name[1];
                    Path path = Paths.get(settingsPath);
                    def dependency = path.getParent().resolve(dir).normalize();
                    outStream.println(dependency);
                    if(!projectDependencies.contains("${dependency}")){
                        projectDependencies.add("${dependency}")
                        if(new File("${dependency}/settings.gradle").exists()){
                            computeAllDependencies("${dependency}/settings.gradle",projectDependencies);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Test1.setOut(System.out);
return Test1;
```

Updated:

```
import java.nio.file.*

class Test1 implements Serializable{

    def script;

    Test1(def script){
        this.script = script;
    }

    def gatherAllDependencies(String settingsPath){
        List projectDependencies = [];
        computeAllDependencies(settingsPath,projectDependencies);
        return projectDependencies;
    }

    def computeAllDependencies(String settingsPath,List projectDependencies){
        new File(settingsPath).splitEachLine('='){line ->
            if(line[1]!=null){
                this.script.echo("Entire Project Name is ${line[1]}");
                def name = line[1].split('\'');
                if(name.length==3){
                    def dir = name[1];
                    Path path = Paths.get(settingsPath);
                    def dependency = path.getParent().resolve(dir).normalize();
                    this.script.echo(dependency);
                    if(!projectDependencies.contains("${dependency}")){
                        projectDependencies.add("${dependency}")
                        if(new File("${dependency}/settings.gradle").exists()){
                            computeAllDependencies("${dependency}/settings.gradle",projectDependencies);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
def a =  new Test1(script:this);
return a;
```

dependents(in JenkinsFile) is always empty despite the same code working fine in Jenkins Script Console. I could not debug it as none of my println statements are logged anywhere

Can someone guide me as to where i am going wrong

Comment: You can add println to your script, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149652/println-in-call-method-of-vars-foo-groovy-works-but-not-in-method-in-class/42548477#42548477

Comment: @JonS thanks for the reply.  I am new to groovy and I tried implementing what u suggested. But now there is a java.io.NotSerializableException: Test1 Caused by: an exception which occurred:in field script

Comment: I think you are hitting the NotSerializable issue described here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230612967-Pipeline-The-pipeline-even-if-successful-ends-with-java-io-NotSerializableException. Have you considered putting the code in a pipeline library and using @NonCPS? More here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/  . But I might try and do that in a Gradle task with another grade project. Easier to call Gradle tooling in pipeline.

Comment: @macg33zr Yes mac. I have added Serializable to class which solved the issue(plz refer to updated section). I am yet to see any output on my console :(

Comment: @macg33zr also mentioned `@NonCPS`, which is likely the next hurdle you're facing. Another possibility is that you've hit a non-approved method in the sandbox: go to `/scriptApprvoal` and adjust if so.

Comment: @rbellamy i didnt find any service deployed on /scriptApproval in Jenkins. Did u mean the Groovy Scripting console ?

Comment: Nope, not the "Groovy Scripting console." I meant the UI to the [Script Security Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin).