# groovy, script:this and jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Based on this:
[println in "call" method of "vars/foo.groovy" works, but not in method in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149652/println-in-call-method-of-vars-foo-groovy-works-but-not-in-method-in-class)

I am trying to get my head around printing to the console from classes created in a Jenkins pipeline using [jenkins shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). I have the following:

**MyPipeline.groovy**

```
node("test") {
  stage("Test") {
          def a = new A(script:this)
          echo "Calling A.a()"
          a.a()
  }
}
```

**A.groovy**

```
class A {
    Script script;
    public void a() {
        script.echo("Hello from A")

        def b = new B(script)
        echo "Calling B.b()"
        b.b()
    }
}
```

**B.groovy**

```
class B {
    Script script;
    public void b() {
        script.echo("Hello from B")
    }
}
```

When I run that I get:

```
"Hello from A"
```

but then I get the error from B:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: samples.B(samples.MyPipeline)
```

How do I make it possible to print to console/build log in my classes also when delegating to other classes - like B in the above case?

As suggested by below answer I have now tried to update **A.groovy** to:

```
class A {
    Script script;
    public void a() {
        script.echo("Hello from A")
        def b = new B()
        b.script = script
        //def b = new B(script)
        echo "Calling B.b()"
        b.b()
    }
}
```

But that just gives a new error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: samples.A.echo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Calling B.b()]
Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), getAt(java.lang.String), wait(), a(), every(), grep()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per groovy's [Initializing beans with named parameters and the default constructor](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html)

Just call empty constructor and set the parameter script

```
def b = new B()

b.script = script
```

> With a bean like:
>
> class Server {
>       String name
>       Cluster cluster }
>
> Instead of setting each setter in subsequent statements as follows:
>
> def server = new Server()
>
> server.name = "Obelix"
>
> server.cluster = aCluster

Also replace the following echo

```
 echo "Calling B.b()"
```

To using `script.echo` method:

```
 script.echo("Calling B.b()")
```

Comment: Updated my post with your suggestion and it gives another error

Comment: Ah yes that works now, I think you are missing a " in the last line of your answer, should be: script.echo("Calling B.b()"), right?