# How to use build in pipelinefunctions in a member function?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Aim is to use the buil in groovy-function in a member function of a class.
Running the following code with default jenkins in ubuntu18.04 leads to the following error.

It looks like jenkins is searching for a function called 'dir' in defined in the class itself.

If important I'll check pipeline version an jenkins vaersion later.

**copy&past pipelinescript:**

```
class notworkingClass {

    notworkingClass(){}
    public MyFunction(){
        dir('/my/local/folder'){
            dosomething() // never reached
        }    
    }
}

def x = new notworkingClass()
x.MyFunction()
```

**This is the stack trace:**

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: notworkingClass.dir() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [/my/local/folder, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@372fc690]
Possible solutions: wait(), dump(), find(), any(), is(java.lang.Object), every()
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at notworkingClass.MyFunction(WorkflowScript:5)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:12)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cutton Eye   I found some message from [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps), I think the explanation is : Library classes cannot directly call steps such as sh or git, but we can call it through a Scripted Pipeline

Comment: ok, thank you for taking the effort to create a account to answer this question! I'll have a look at it =)

Comment: So it's basically not implemented that a lib has access to the special pipeline functions. This script-command I've found is then something like a like a backdoor? With other words, those pipeline functions are private part of a class "script" and so can't called directly. You need the "script" kind of a handle to call those private functions? (ps: edit your answere as long you have not enough rep for comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution... just wan't do say, it's not obvious and I've no idea why this is working at all. If somebody could explaint this to me, I would be more then happy! [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149652/println-in-call-method-of-vars-foo-groovy-works-but-not-in-method-in-class/42548477)

The magic line is this `Script script` thing in the sample class.

```
class A {
    Script script;
    public void a() {
        script.echo("Hello")
        script.sh('pwd')
    }
}

node('master'){
  def a = new A(script:this)
  echo "Calling A.a()"
  a.a()
}
```

It's like take this context as class and reference it to the variable or something...

But i still look for a way in not cheating with the constructor,  a member function like this:

```
public testFunction(MyArg){
  hudson.jenkins.hidding.function.entry.echo(MyArg)
  // from my understanding, there must be something like this
}
```

By hitting

```
println(WorkflowScript.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique())
```

it shows that it at least not part of the WorkflowScript:

```
[$build, $buildNoException, blubb, equals, evaluate, #
 getBinding, getClass, getMetaClass, getProperty, hashCode,
 invokeMethod, main, notify, notifyAll, print, printf, println,
 run, setBinding, setMetaClass, setProperty, sleep, toString, wait]
```